# Reload page when UIWebView rebounds

Tags: ios, uiview, uiwebview, uiscrollview

Is it possible to have a UIWebView reload it's content when the page is scrolled to the bottom and the UIWebView rebounds? Are there any examples for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that a WebView contains a scrollview.  Have your viewcontroller implement the `UIScrollViewDelegate`:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

Then you can set the delegate for the UIScrollView:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Set self as scroll view protocol
    webView.scrollView.delegate = self;
}
```

In the scrollview delegate `scrollViewDidScroll`, you can detect the top and bottom being reached:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{   
    if(scrollView.contentOffset.y >= (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height)){
        NSLog(@"BOTTOM REACHED");
        [webView reload];
    }
    if(scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0.0){
        NSLog(@"TOP REACHED");
    }
}
```

With this, you can detect when top and bottom are reached, and reload when appropriate.